# View doesn't appear

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So I've created a native control, given it some layout options, added it to a StackView and it doesn't appear.

```
var calendar = new RadCalendarView(Forms.Context);
calendar.LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams(
    Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
    Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent
);
stackLayout.Children.Add(calendar);
```

How do I make the view appear?

Comment: Does the StackLayout appear ?

Comment: Are you using Telerik controls here and if you are why are you using the native control instead of using the xamarin forms RadCalendar

Comment: @G.hakim I was hoping for an increase in speed.

Comment: @Greggz An activity indicator within the stackview is visible.

Comment: I guess you should simply use the RadCalender and check if that appears

Comment: It does. I've been trying to work out what the renderer does to make the control appear but it's too complicated.

Comment: Have you tried to create it in axml?

Comment: Could you please share the codes of your created native control?